# What is a sitemap and why do I need it?

Tags: web, sitemap

I am creating a new website and I wonder what is really a sitemap and what does it add to the website?
From my understanding it is a tree diagram of my pages and their connections is this for the user to access? Is it for the search engines?

thanks a lot.

Comment: This may be better for webmaster SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it is for the website-visitor to have an overview over your pages, as you said, a tree-view of your site. It is also good to have one for search engines, so they are able to find all your pages.

You can also create sitemaps specifically for search engines which are not visible for the end-user. Many create sitemaps to boost their rankings for search engines.

Answer (score -2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site_map

Personally I found sitemaps very useful in case a webdesigner messed up the structure of the menu, so the sitemap was the only way to navigate.

Especially if the menu contains many subgroups a clean tree structure helps to keep an overview.

So all in all it helps showing the user the whole size of the webpage preventing him from overlooking big parts of the whole website and getting stuck in a subsection.

P.S.: According to Wikipedia you also help search engines.